# Why are there only 63 bits in java.lang.Long(MAX_VALUE)?

Tags: java, binary, max, long-integer

Can anyone explain the difference between the output from the two println statements below?

```
public class LongTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffffL));
        System.out.println(java.lang.Long.toBinaryString(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The first line of output contains 64 binary digits. The second line only contains 63 binary digits.

If if 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffffL were greater than Long.MAX_VALUE, I would expect a compiler error. But the program obviously does compile, so the difference in output must be due to some other reason.

Comment: might be a 64bit value, but 1 bit is used for the sign, so you effectly have 63 bits of range.

Comment: Probably [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) whereas the first bit is the sign bit.

Comment: `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7fffffffffffffffL`.

Comment: FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF = -1L

Comment: It doesn't compile: The literal 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff of type int is out of range

Comment: Yes, it does compile here with javac 1.7.0_40.

Comment: True, 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff would be out of range. But as a long literal (with a trailing L as was used in the sample code) it does compile here using javac 1.7.0_40.

Comment: Oops. I see that in my sample code the terminating L was missing after all. Sorry -- I was running on little sleep and must only have fixed that in my on-disk copy. Will correct the code in the post itself now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a Long is signed, one bit is used to store the sign. `Long.MAX_VALUE` therefore is 2^63 - 1.

See documentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Comment: Yes, that's it. As a decimal number 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff = -1.

Comment: Typo in my previous comment. The numeric literal should end with L.